# How is a magnetic field different from a electromagnetic field?

Tags: classical-mechanics, electromagnetic-radiation, magnetic-fields, electric-fields, classical-electrodynamics

I am sure this question has been asked, and I know the difference (in elementary terms) but the internet is filled with ***propaganda*** that 4 milliGauss will cause leukemia in children of an electromagnetic field, where a normal fridge magnet can normally contain 50 Gauss and the magnetic field of the earth at the surface is much higher than 4 milliGauss.  Why are people freaked out about 4 mG of electromagnetic fields, but thousands of G from a strong permanent magnet has no coverage?!?!  Is there a fundamental difference between the two?  I cant think of any myself but I am not very smart in the end.

Edit: a single source of propaganda as requested from a contributor to this thread.  Source from  https://thetruthaboutcancer.com/are-microwaves-safe/.  "Exposures of just 4 milligauss have been firmly linked to leukemia."  Google that quote and every result quotes that exact line.

Comment: Could you share an example of this so-called propaganda?

Comment: Source from  https://thetruthaboutcancer.com/are-microwaves-safe/.  "Exposures of just 4 milligauss have been firmly linked to leukemia."  Google that quote and every top non science result quotes that exact line (9 out of the top 10 results)

Comment: Thanks for the link. I definitely will not start a discussion about this article here, just keep in mind this site also has this post https://thetruthaboutcancer.com/are-vaccines-safe-survey/, which by itself has enough controversial material to start a war. This being said, IMHO I think Physics.SE is perhaps not the most suitable place for your question

Comment: I dont want a discussion about the article.  You asked for the link.  I want to know the difference between an electromagnetic field and a magnetic field.

Comment: @ChristopherSheffield, there is really only one type of field: an electromagnetic field.

Comment: You're right, probably I misinterpreted your post. Sorry about that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will answer the title:

> How is a magnetic field different from a electromagnetic field?

A magnetic field, does not change in time by itself. If one takes a permanent magnet and sets it in oscillation, an electromagnetic field will appear, i.e light of very large wavelength, and thus not visible. [Changing magnetic fields](http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/302l/lectures/node117.html) create electric fields and then radiation in electromagnetic waves, and changing electric field create magnetic fields and radiation in electromagnetic waves.

The magnetic field  of [electromagnetic radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_radiation) are much lower in value than the single magnetic field of a magnet , that is the discrepancy in the numbers you quote, between gauss for magnets and mgauss for radiation , which is the rootmeansquare of the field

[image: elm]

the red is the electric field the blue the magnetic as the wave propagates.

Now the so called dangers from microwave radiation , debunked by the answer of Steve, are presumed to come from the excitations and deexcitations of molecular and lattice bonds within the food, generating dangerous chemical changes. The magnetic field strength is a funny unit to use, but go figure.

Comment: I think the alarmist claim pertained to the AC (60 Hz) fields from power lines.  Very different from microwave ovens at 2.45 GHz, which would heat tissue.  At the lower frequency, there is a possibility that the varying magnetic field could induce weak electric currents in tissue.

Answer (score -2):

Good grief.

Some of the physics in that article is true. It gives a reasonable summary of what microwaves are, and how they heat food. Microwaves do leak from an oven. It correctly characterises microwaves as non-ionising. It is true that microwave cooking deforms the structure of molecules.

I believe also it makes correct claims about some effects that would *not* be considered the realm of physics. For example, that cooking produces carcinogens, tends to destroy certain vitamins, that certain plastics are believed to leach carcinogens into food when heated.

But where to start on the unsupported claims, the subtle misrepresentations, and the outright falsehoods?

Did the Nazis invent the microwave oven and use them on the Eastern front? I would say not - it was an adjunct of the technological development of radar, and the first commercial microwaves were developed after WW2. They were large floor-standing beasts that require a supply of electricity, and astronomically expensive by today's standards. They would not have been superior to solid-fuel cookers.

Did the Soviets ban the microwave oven on safety grounds? I would say not - there is simply no evidence to support the claim, and much evidence of the Soviets having produced consumer microwave models.

Does microwaving cause food to lose it's "food value"? I would say not - there is no evidence of an appreciable adverse effect on the calorific value or digestibility of microwaved food. Cooking in general assists digestibility.

Implicitly, are microwaves the only kind of oven that "leak radiation"? No, all ovens leak infrared radiation (as does hot food itself), and electric cookers of any kind also generate localised EMF.

Implicitly, is microwave cooking the *only* kind of cooking that produces carcinogens, or destroys vitamins? No, all forms of cooking do so - particularly if the food is permitted to burn, brown, or crisp. The chemical effects are entirely attributable to the effects of heat (from any source), not to microwave irradiation.

Implicitly, is cooking food unhealthy? No. It destroys a wide variety of pathogens (some of which can be promptly deadly) introduced by the natural environment and also by prior handling and preparation, breaks down harmful chemicals present in *some* foods, and increases the biological availability and digestibility of the food (it's "food value").

Is microwaving *especially* harmful in any way, against any other form of cooking? I would say there is no evidence that it is.

Does the article characterise the situation in a way that would allow people to grasp and properly evaluate "risks", and promote clear and whole thinking? No.

As a final note, the same sorts of fallacious reasoning are present in the vaccine article linked by @caverac in the comments. The preposterous claim that "unvaccinated children are healthier" seems to make no mention of the devastating health effects of the diseases which are being vaccinated against, or the risk of children acquiring them if they are unvaccinated. My headmaster at school had suffered with polio as a child which left him permanently disabled in one leg - and that was considered considered a mild case, in that many who contracted the disease were left with even more extreme disabilities or killed outright.

Comment: Thanks for the response but I wasn't asking you to debunk the website, I was asking the difference between electromagnetic fields and magnetic fields.  The link was added because someone asked for it.

Comment: @ChristopherSheffield, if you merely want a basic outline of electromagnetism, why don't you just look it up? I can't understand why you referred to the claims made on some charlatan website, if you didn't want it's charlatan nature to be addressed - people are "freaked out" by 4mGs whilst unconcerned about 50Gs, because they are being uncritical in the first place. And if the charlatans peddling misinformation were too extreme and attacked too many ordinary home appliances, it would create material hardship and their victims would be more likely to examine and reject the claims.

Comment: @Steve He mentioned those claims because they were the basis of the question.  OP even mentions that information was added on the request of other posters.

Comment: @JMac, it was far from clear from the body text (even before the edit) that the real question was merely that contained in the title. I took the question to be "why are people freaking out...", thus my evaluation of the link. I was assuming the OP would make the appropriate inferences, that the apparent contradiction to which he refers - between the different levels of concern for microwave ovens and fridge magnets - was accounted for by recognising the inherent mendacity of the article's claims about microwave ovens.

Comment: It was pretty clear